# Transforming tag with regex replace

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have an tag to convert. I'm try do this with php functions:
How i can do that transformation?

```
content before @[youtube](XIMLoLxmTDw) content after =>  content before <div class="iframe-wrapper"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XIMLoLxmTDw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe></div> content after
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getStringBetween($str,$from,$to)
{
    $sub = substr($str, strpos($str,$from)+strlen($from),strlen($str));
    return substr($sub,0,strpos($sub,$to));
}
$string='<div class="iframe-wrapper"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XIMLoLxmTDw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe></div>';
$start='embed/';
 $end='"';
$idYoutube=getStringBetween($string , $start,$end);
echo $idYoutube;
```

Comment: Make sure always to add some textual (non-code) info to explain why your answer works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand you but perhaps this code snippet can help you?

```
<?php

$re = '/\@\[youtube\]\((.*)\)/';
$str = '@[youtube](XIMLoLxmTDw)';
$subst = '<div class="iframe-wrapper"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe></div>';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);

echo $result;
```

[Proof of concept on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KcItCU/1)

Comment: Cool way. thanks. I will learn regex. sorry by the question

Comment: No worries. Happy coding.